# if checkbox is checked php

Tags: php, if-statement, checkbox, checked

If checkbox is checked I want to store a value in php variable and for unchecked store another value

```
        <script>
        $('input[type="checkbox"][name="change"]').change(function() {
                if(this.checked) {
                    <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ORDER BY sl_no ASC"?>
                } else {
                    <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ORDER BY sl_no DESC"?>
                }
            });
        </script>

        <input type="checkbox" name="change">
```

Comment: You are mixing Javascript and PHP. Please keep in mind that JS is client-side and PHP is server-side. You have to send an ajax request to your PHP script when calling `change` event handler in your Javascript part.

Comment: See [When and where does JavaScript run, how about PHP? Can I combine the two?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25093905)

Answer (score 2):

You cant mix PHP with JavaScript. To send something back to the server, you have to use a form or ajax.
Since ajax isn't a little bit harder to learn, and I dont know how much you already know, you should use forms

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="change">
    <input type="submit" />
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['change'])) {
            echo "checkbox checked";
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

To do this with ajax, you have to define an ajax handler script with some logic

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['checked']) && $_POST['checked'] == '1') {
        echo 'checked';
    } else {
        echo 'not checked';
    }
?>
```

and add some more client side code(using jQuery)

```
    <script>
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name="change"]').change(function() {
            $.post('ajax.php',
                { checked: this.checked ? '1' : '0' },
                function(data) {
                    $('.result').html(data);
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Actually I want to sort a table by ascending or descending with checkbox in php

Comment: I can't afford to use submit button here

Comment: then you have to use the ajax solution and return the table inside the ajax file

Comment: how do I collect post value in ajax.php file

Comment: @Maurize Sure you can, but JavaScript can't execute PHP directly - and thats what the op want to do