# php in <script> tags executing without call why?

Tags: javascript, php, session

The php in method signout is executing without call . At first the username is echoed fine , but second echo below signout method shows that its null. It should be called when the singout link is clicked . Why is this happening ?

```
<?php   echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> // this echo show real value

<script>

function singout()
{
    <?php   $_SESSION['username']='null'; ?>
    window.alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>");

}

<?php   echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> // but this echo show null value

</script>

<a onclick="singout();" href="login.html" style="float: right">singout</a>
```

Comment: Coding for Server/Client architecture 101...

Comment: Was just trying to find a quick link - essentially PHP runs on the server it's always executed before the anything on the client (HTML, JavaScript) therefore you can't use JavaScript to execute PHP... unless you're doing it in a separate call with Ajax

Comment: Thanks @CD001 for helping

Comment: Ah, found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093905/when-and-where-does-javascript-run-how-about-php-can-i-combine-the-two - that should pretty much answer any question you've got about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP is being called without the JS Function being called because on browser load each PHP line is procedurally called. Just because your PHP line is within a JS function doesn't mean it isn't called on browser load

Comment: So how should I resolve and achieve the functionality I want , any solution ?

Comment: Thanks @iJamesPHP for helping

Comment: There's not exactlty a solution for interacting with PHP variables in your Javascript, could you not just redirect them to a page called logout.php then call session_start(); followed by session_destroy();? If you dont want any sort of page redirection then just run the logout.php by doing a POST request to the file with some random dummy variables, merely to trigger the logout.php without redirecting the user