# Get a value from javascript and assign it to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, variables

I have this JavaScript code

```
var list = "";
$.each(data.result.products, function (i, item) {
    var prices = item.salePrice;
    list = list +
        '<h3>' + item.productTitle + '</h3>' +
        '<h4>' +  item.salePrice + ' </h4>' +
        '<?php $price = "" ?>' +
        ;
})
```

I want `item.salePrice` in PHP variable `<?php $price = "" ?>`. What will be the best solution to assign price value to PHP variable.

Comment: You just can't assign server side variable from client side script.

Comment: Best solution? Best solution is to understand what is js and where is executed and what is php and where is executed

Comment: AJAX - and then what the two above said.

Comment: There is a good answer here which explains this well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093905/when-and-where-does-javascript-run-how-about-php-can-i-combine-the-two#25093906

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something on server from client which is impossible the way you do it. Javascript is run on client side, that means you can´t access server because you don´t have direct access to the server. What allows you to make calls to the server from client is jQuery.ajax() which performs asynchronous call to the server. That way you can make server changes. The way you do it, you just insert some php code which will never be run, because the site is already fully loaded.