# How to pass JQuery variable to $_POST key in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

As i specified in the title, i am using JQuery for processing $_POST requests
the sample code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var goal_type=[];

        goal_type[1]="<?php echo $_POST['goal_type1'];?>";
        goal_type[2]="<?php echo $_POST['goal_type2'];?>";
        goal_type[3]="<?php echo $_POST['goal_type3'];?>";
        goal_type[4]="<?php echo $_POST['goal_type4'];?>";
        goal_type[5]="<?php echo $_POST['goal_type5'];?>";
        goal_type[6]="<?php echo $_POST['goal_type6'];?>";
        goal_type[7]="<?php echo $_POST['goal_type7'];?>";
        goal_type[8]="<?php echo $_POST['goal_type8'];?>";
  });
</script>
```

And my requirement is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var goal_type=[];

       for(var i=1;i<=8;i++)
       {
        var goals="goal_type"+i;
        goal_type="<?php echo $_POST["'+goals+'"]?>";
        console.log("Value is:"+goal_type);
       }      
});
</script>
```

But it prints blank on console.
please acknowledge me how to i pass "goals"(JQUERY VARIABLE) into $_POST['']

Comment: Added an answer instead, as I initially missed you use an array variable

Comment: Why do you use jQuery for this? loading jQuery for just a simple array is a bit too heavy in my opinion.

Comment: @DennisSpierenburg OP is not using jQuery to process the array, it use plain javascript.

Comment: `var goals="goal_type"+i; goal_type="<?php echo $_POST["'+goals+'"]?>";` - this makes no sense whatsoever; and if you are not aware of that, then you need to go first of all inform yourself about how the technologies you are using basically work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093905/when-and-where-does-javascript-run-how-about-php-can-i-combine-the-two

Comment: @CBroe The main issues here, which I described in my answer, none of that is mentioned in the link you provided. How does it relate to OP's question?... I mean, I can't see how they are trying to run PHP client side, just how to build an array with concat'd string/value.

Comment: @LGSon `goals` is a JavaScript variable (containing value `goal_type1` etc. during the client-side for loop), and then they are trying to use that on the next line `<?php echo $_POST["'+goals+'"]?>` to try and access a certain entry inside $_POST.

Comment: @CBroe You might be right...for me that was so far off so I didn't see how it possibly could be that way :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way is using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var goal_type=<?= json_encode($_POST) ?>;
        console.log(goal_type); //look at your console
  });
</script>
```

then you may access them by exact same `key` of `$_POST`.

`var someGoal = goal_type[1];`

---

If you want to filter passed `$_POST`, then you have to create another array and pass desired keys of `$_POST` into that, and then you can print it as a json object into your `JavaScript` code.

```
 <?php 
    $filtered_post=[
        1=>$_POST['some_key'],
        2=>$_POST['another_key'],
        //...,
    ];
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
         var goal_type=<?= json_encode($filtered_post) ?>;
         console.log(goal_type); //look at your console
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just your syntax error.

```
goal_type="<?php echo $_POST["'+goals+'"]?>";
```

It will returns nothing because there's no `$_POST` value with key `'+goals+'` therefore `goal_type` is just empty.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var goal_type=[];

        <?php for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) : ?>
            goal_type[<?php echo $i; ?>] = "<?php echo $_POST['goal_type'.$i]; ?>";
            console.log("Value is: " + goal_type[<?php echo $i; ?>]);
        <?php endfor; ?>
    });
</script>
```